# Fail when dropping target variable in decision tree with python

Tags: python, decision-tree

I'm trying to execute a decision tree with sckitlearn like this:

```
from sklearn.tree import DecisionTreeClassifier
from sklearn import tree

data = df_train
target = data['SeriousDlqin2yrs']
#Split in train and test
X_train,X_test,target_train,target_test = train_test_split(data, target, 
test_size=0.33, random_state=3)
#Drop target variable
X_train = X_test.drop(['SeriousDlqin2yrs'],axis=1,inplace=False)
X_test = X_test.drop(['SeriousDlqin2yrs'],axis=1,inplace=False)
#fit the tree
tree_clf = tree.DecisionTreeClassifier(max_depth=3).fit(X_train, target_train)
#make prediction
predicted_tree = tree_clf.predict(X_test)
print(classification_report(target_test, predicted_tree))
```

And I don't know why, I get this error:

```
ValueError: Number of labels=96427 does not match number of samples=47495
```

If I don't drop the target variable it works and I get and AUC score of 1.0, which is also strange

```
from sklearn.metrics import roc_auc_score
roc_auc_score(target_test, predicted_tree)

Out[139]:1.0
```

Does anybody know why is this not working?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have this line in your code:

```
X_train = X_test.drop(['SeriousDlqin2yrs'],axis=1,inplace=False)
```

It seems like you are storing the test data in the train data after the drop. Try using X_train instead of X_test in that line of the code.
Alternatively, just use inplace=True and don't reassign it.